# Jquery image carousel make it circular carousel so it is “infinite”

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this image carousel but I would like to make it circular so that it will infinity scroll how would I modify this code so that it will do this? Also if possible how would I make it auto scroll?

HTML:

```
<div id="my_carousel">
<ul>
    <li>some content...</li>
    <li>some content...</li>
    <li>some content...</li>
    <li>some content...</li>
    <li>some content...</li>
    <li>some content...</li>
    .....
</ul>
```

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    var step = 2; 
    var current = 0; 
    var maximum = $('#my_carousel ul li').size(); 
    var visible = 2; 
    var speed = 200; 
    var liSize = 331;
    var carousel_height = 161;


    var ulSize = liSize * maximum;   
    var divSize = liSize * visible;  

    $('#my_carousel ul').css("width", ulSize+"px").css("left", -(current * liSize)).css("position", "absolute");

    $('#my_carousel').css("width", divSize+"px").css("height", carousel_height+"px").css("visibility", "visible").css("overflow", "hidden").css("position", "relative"); 

    $('.btnnext').click(function() { 
        if(current + step < 0 || current + step > maximum - visible) {return; }
        else {
            current = current + step;
            $('#my_carousel ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.btnprev').click(function() { 
        if(current - step < 0 || current - step > maximum - visible) {return; }
        else {
            current = current - step;
            $('#my_carousel ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$('.btnnext').click(function() { 
    if(current + step < 0 || current + step > maximum - visible) {
        current = maximum - step;
    }
    else {
        current = current + step;
    }

    $('#my_carousel ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
    return false;
});

$('.btnprev').click(function() { 
    if(current - step < 0 || current - step > maximum - visible) {
        current = 0 + step;
    }
    else {
        current = current - step;
    }

    $('#my_carousel ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
    return false;
});
```

You might have to tinker with the numbers a bit, but this should reset your current value each time regardless of it's position at either the end or the beginning of the carousel. If it's at the end, it should jump to the beginning. If it's at the beginning it should cycle to the maximum (end).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [JCrousell Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) Plugin. You can also use [circular property](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html) of [JCrousell](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) Plugin. which you are using right now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think, you should use if something is already available. Its a waste of time writing whole code and css if something is already available.

Comment: I would agree but since I already have the custom code working apart from the circular part then not really a waste of time.

Comment: @AlphaMale: Unless you're trying to learn something about it rather than just trying to ship a site.